# How to Test Android Wear App With Both Devices

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I am new to Android programming. I am developing a wearable application. So far, I have a mobile and wear module. All I want to test is that a button on the handheld app triggers a notification to appear on the wearable device.

To test it, I have both physical devices (Watch and Mobile). I have the LG Watch R and an Android mobile device. I have ADB debugging enabled on both devices. I downloaded the Android Wear app on my handheld and it syncs fine with the watch. I have both devices connected to my laptop through USB.

How do I test the whole project?

Do I have to run the mobile module first and then the wear module? I tried researching Google's examples but they only explain a handheld connected to a wear emulator.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter which is loaded on first unless you are debugging. If you're just monitoring Logcat then you can switch between the two devices fairly easily in Android Studio.

You don't need to rebuild each of the separate modules each time either. For example, if you make changes to the handheld module and not the wear module then you only have to build the handheld.

Comment: Thanks Disco! Cleared things up a bit